# How can I set up tiered volume discounts without enacting a waterfall effect of multiple discounts being applied?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, promotions

Trying to set up tiered volume discounts and can't figure out how to *not* have multiple discounts get applied when the cart total meets minimum criteria for more than one discount.

So the simple discounts I'm trying to have applied are here:[image: Screenshot from spreadsheet containing discount structure]

[image: Examples of multiple discounts in the CMS Admin and the result of multiple discounts being applied in the cart]

I understand why Craft is applying both: Because the order meets the criteria for both Purchase Quantities. Is there a way I can specify a range, or other workaround?

Answer (score 1):

Currently at Craft Commerce 1.1 this is not possible with the current discount engine.

We would need to implement features like a min qty *AND* a max qty for the discount rules. It is on our radar.

Fee free to vote for extended discount conditions features here: http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/295386-commerce/filters/top

Comment: Posted this to the Craft feature request forum. Thanks, Luke!